# Yield section if a certain controller is used

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel layout, I would like to display a menu bar if a certain controller is used.

How would I detect a controller inside blade?

For example:

```
// Layout main.blade.php

if(Controller == admin){

   @yield('menu')

}
```

I know the syntax is wrong. Just to give you an idea what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

There's a package for that: https://github.com/digithis/activehelper. It explains in detail how you can use it and it has helped me to do the same as what you're asking.

For a one-liner, you can use `Route::currentRouteAction()` assuming your routes are configured for example as:

```
Route::get('test', array('as'=>'test', 'uses'=>'TestsController@test'));
```

Very concrete for your question, you can use:

```
if (explode( '@' , Route::currentRouteAction())[0]) == 'controllerName')
{
     // your code here
}
```

Comment: Thank you lowerends, but is there no one-liner boolean function that can tell me what controller is being used in a view?